# Error in Unity3D "There is already a virtual axis named XXX registered." in VirtualInput.cs

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Please, help.
There was a problem in Unity3D, with scripts from standard assets.
Namely in VirtualInput.cs

On the Internet there were answers with the correction of the code on other versions of Unity3D.
And here is another method

```c
public void RegisterVirtualAxis(CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis axis)
        {
            // check if we already have an axis with that name and log and error if we do
            if (m_VirtualAxes.ContainsKey(axis.name))
            {
                Debug.LogError("There is already a virtual axis named " + axis.name + " registered.");
            }
            else
            {
                // add any new axes
                m_VirtualAxes.Add(axis.name, axis);

                // if we dont want to match with the input manager setting then revert to always using virtual
                if (!axis.matchWithInputManager)
                {
                    m_AlwaysUseVirtual.Add(axis.name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unity Console Error Next:

There is already a virtual axis named Vertical registered.
There is already a virtual axis named Horizontal registered.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to the problem, and remake method:

```c
public void RegisterVirtualAxis(CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis axis)
        {
            // check if we already have an axis with that name and log and error if we do
            if (m_VirtualAxes.ContainsKey(axis.name))
            {
                //Debug.LogError("There is already a virtual axis named " + axis.name + " registered.");
                m_VirtualAxes.Remove(axis.name);

                m_VirtualAxes.Add(axis.name, axis);

                if (!axis.matchWithInputManager)
                {
                    m_AlwaysUseVirtual.Add(axis.name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // add any new axes
                m_VirtualAxes.Add(axis.name, axis);

                // if we dont want to match with the input manager setting then revert to always using virtual
                if (!axis.matchWithInputManager)
                {
                    m_AlwaysUseVirtual.Add(axis.name);
                }
            }
        }
```